# How to wrap a link to all images inside a div?

Tags: javascript, jquery, image, hyperlink

I have something like this:

```
<img class="photo" src="www.example.com" />
<img class="photo" src="www.example2.com" />
<img class="photo" src="www.example3.com" />
```

And I need to get this:

```
<a href="www.example.com" class="link">
    <img class="photo" src="www.example.com" />
</a>
<a href="www.example2.com" class="link">
    <img class="photo" src="www.example.com2" />
</a>
<a href="www.example3.com" class="link">
    <img class="photo" src="www.example.com3" />
</a>
```

I need to add the link, the href with the same code as the SRC of each image, and a class.

I was trying to do it like this:

```
$('.photo').wrapAll('<a>');
```

But it doesn't even work.
What am I doing wrong?

Comment: `$('.photo').wrapAll('<a />');` ? Or `$('.photo').wrapAll('<a></a>');`? http://api.jquery.com/wrapAll/

Comment: It doesn't work. The images are loaded with jquery with:                 d_row.append(img);

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Because the hrefs will all be different, you'll need to use [each](http://api.jquery.com/each).

```
$('img.photo').each( function() {
    var $img = $(this),
        href = $img.attr('src');
    $img.wrap('<a href="' + href + '" class="link"></a>');
});
```

Note that [wrapAll](http://api.jquery.com/wrapall) isn't what you want anyway as it will take all the elements and wrap them with a single anchor tag. If you weren't using an anchor that needs a different href for each element, [wrap](http://api.jquery.com/wrap) would work by itself and wrap each one individually.

Comment: Sounds very nice but it seems it doesn't work on my code.
It might be because images are not loaded on the website, they are added by javascript one by one with this:                 d_row.append(img);
Any help? Thanks.

Comment: If you're adding it dynamically, either wrap it before appending it or simply construct the HTML you're appending to include the link before adding it to the DOM.

Comment: I have tried it with this code and the rest of replies and no one did anything to the images. It didn't add anything.

Answer (score 1):

`$('img').wrap("<a href='foo'>")` will work just fine.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$('.photo').before('<a href="www.example3.com" class="link">');
$('.photo').after('</a>');
```

And if you want

```
$( '.photo' ).each( function() {
    var mySrc = $( this ).attr( "src" );
    $( this ).before( '<a href="' + mySrc + '" class="link">' ) );
    $( this ).after( '</a>' ) );
});
```

I hope this works for you...

Comment: My images are loaded with javascript after                 d_row.append(img);
So this doesn't work well.